# Reorder list rows in flex mobile app

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, mobile, air, flex4.6

How can I let the user reorder the rows of a list in a flex mobile app?

You know, you see it a lot in native iOS apps. Usually you hit an Edit button at the top of a list view. Each row then gets a thumb icon that lets you move the rows around in the list.

This might be totally obvious, but I'm writing my first mobile app in flex and can't seem to find an example anywhere.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Spark List control supports Drag and Drop, besides dragging and dropping with the list itself, you can also do so between two different list controls.  To enable the feature, you could set    dragEnabled,    dragMoveEnabled,    dropEnabled properties to true, more details may be found in this [help document](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7cfd.html).

To enable the feature as you described, you could set those drag and drop properties to true when the edit mode is enabled.  Optionally, you could also display a drag handler (as decorator).

Update: For mobile application, there is a [write-up](http://flexponential.com/2011/06/21/using-drag-and-drop-with-a-spark-list-in-a-mobile-flex-application/) on how to get around with mobile limitation of drag-and-drop.

Comment: The documentation says drag & drop is not supported in mobile apps. Is this wrong or did I misinterpret the documentation?

Comment: Forgot to include the work-around of mobile list drag and drop.

Comment: Just keep in mind that the work-around really is nothing more than a work-around. Not that it doesn't work, but it's not very nice as the performance is very, very bad. Works perfectly fine in the device simulator, but on an actual device it is sluggish as hell. So not production ready.